# In Javascript - How do I change the image a variable points to without reloading it?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm making a rudimentary game to learn Javascript, and drawing to the HTML canvas with images. I preload the images so they display when the game starts, but after the first time the images don't display, suggesting they're being reloaded.

This is executed on page load:

```
function preload() {
for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++){
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}
preload("images/background.png", "images/character.png", "images/dragon.png", "images/humanOpponent.png","images/ooze.png","images/tinyCharacter.png");
```

Part of the function that's called when a battle begins - I know this code is sloppy and things that are handled here should be handled elsewhere, but that's not the focus of the question:

```
youImage.src = "images/character.png";
background.src = "images/background.png";

if (oppType == "Human")
    {oppHealth = humanOpp.maxHP;
    oppImage.src = humanOpp.image;}
if (oppType == "Ooze")
    {oppHealth = ooze.maxHP;
    oppImage.src = ooze.image;}
if (oppType == "Dragon")
    {oppHealth = dragon.maxHP;
    oppImage.src = dragon.image;
    youImage.src = "images/tinycharacter.png";
    background.src = "images/castleBackground.png";}
```

I think what's happening is that the images are being reloaded when this function is called
But this exact code is called when the game starts up - and the images display there. So I'm baffled.

Comment: What is the problem when your game loads? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: There's no problem when the game loads. The images display just fine the first time - it's only each time the combat-start function is called that the images stop being displayed and don't display again until they reload. It works just fine when it's run locally.

Answer (score 0):

Does it makes sense to modify it as follows?

```
var preloadedImages = {};
function preload(images) {
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = images[i][1];
      preloadedImages[images[i][0]] = img;
    }
}
preload([["dragon", "images/dragon.png"], ["human", "images/humanOpponent.png"]]);
```

Then you can just use:

```
if (oppType == "Human") {
    oppHealth = humanOpp.maxHP;
    oppImage = preloadedImages['human'];
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks!

Comment: I should note that I actually sat down to implement it just now and the implementation required placing a bracket around the preload() arguments, so it was along the lines of [["dragon", "images/dragon.png"], ["human", "images/humanOpponent.png"]].